# Manipulating elements after AJAX load()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to manipulate some elements after I load them using .load(). I have everything loading correctly, but I can't seem to target any elements within any of the loaded elements. This seems like something that would be easy, but I just can put my finger on it.

I am using a callback after the elements load, but the DOM seems to not be aware of their existence?

```
function load_page(){
    $('#page_name').load("/page-name/ .page", null, load_complete());
}

function load_complete() {
    $('#page_name .book_img').addClass('hello');
}
```

Ok, this is where I am at now. I have added...

```
$('#wrapper').ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('#page_name .book_img').addClass('hello');
}
```

which works. There must be a difference between the .autoComplete and the callback which is packaged with the .load() function. I don't really like this because it is called every time an AJAX event is finished loading, but it does get me a little further down the road.

Anybody have anything better?

[EDIT]

I also tried...

```
$('#wrapper').ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('#page_name .book_img').addClass('hello');
}
```

Which is kind of nice since it waits till all AJAX calls are done before calling the function. Maybe this is the way to do it, but it still seems like the .load() function would take care of this?

Comment: Can you post the content of /page-name/?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your executing your callback function instead of passing it to the load method:

```
function load_page(){
    // $('#page_name').load("/page-name/ .page", null, load_complete());
    $('#page_name').load("/page-name/ .page", null, load_complete);
}

function load_complete() {
    $('#page_name .book_img').addClass('hello');
}
```

So what was being passed to the load method is null because there is no return value in load_complete

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the javascript that is to manipulate your loaded objects in the item that's getting loaded. This is because it has already ran through all your javascript.

**edit**

Try this, set the asynchronicity to false so it you can add a callback after its loaded.

```
$.ajax ({
  async: false,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "html",
  url: "/page-name/ .page",
  complete: function(){load_complete()};
});
```

**update**

Hey, there's also this shorthand get statement I use occasionally. It surprises me that these are not working in your script..

```
$.get($(this).attr('href'), function(response) { $('#content').html(response); });
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand your answer. The only jquery that needs to be there to manipulate the items is in the callback on the .load() function itself?

Comment: I don't think you can load pieces of the .html in the same way as you can with .load().  I could never get url: "/page-name/ .page" to load, it always throws an error

Comment: hmm you can set the `dataType: html` . I'll update the answer above. If you don't set it explicitly, jQuery just guesses what it thinks the dataType is.

Comment: yeah still doesn't work, it throws a 404 error because it can't find /page-name/%20.page

Comment: dang.. try `dataType: "script"` ? Sorry just throwing ideas out there.. This is where I'm reading from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the HTML takes a bit of time to render. Try adding a delay before accessing the new content:

```
$('#page_name').load("/page-name/ .page", null, window.setTimeout(function(){load_complete()},50);
```

Comment: A timeout assumes that it just happens under 50 miliseconds. Awful idea.

Comment: Yeah, redraws are usually pretty quick.