# Ajax function to button after .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, load, reload

I have a button with the class 'check_button' in the div 'check_div'. I have a Jquery code that if the user clicks on the button, the script send an Ajax request to the server. After that he reloads the div with .load(), so he also reloads the button. The problem is that then the Jquery code doesn't work for the button. I read other Stackoverflow articles but I am new in Ajax and Jquery so I don't know how to solve my problem. Link I found with the same problem (I think): [Manipulating elements after AJAX load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824118/manipulating-elements-after-ajax-load)

Comment: Could you also post the code you've used so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you do 2 calls to the server:

1. AJAX call
2. load

Why not do that in 1 call?

```
  $.ajax({
    url: theurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(req, resulttype, exc)
    {
      // error handling
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
      $('.check_div').html(data.html);
    }
  });
```

In you response from the server you can json encode whaever you want to send back to the client.

As for you question:

Also all dynamically added elements can be used with:

```
$(element).live('click', function() { });
```

Or even better with `.delegate()`:
    $(container).delegate('.check_div', 'click', function() {
    });

in stead of:

```
$(element).click(function() { });
```

For more info check out:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Yes. I have the load and the Ajax request in one. I don't use .html as in your code, but I use .load(). But the live solves the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: Ok, I do that. Need to wait 40 seconds. But is it a problem to use html instead of load?

Comment: @Jordy: load is use to make a request to the server